# Function runs properly when called however always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently making up a sign up form using react and firebase, and I got stuck at validating whether the username given by the user has been used or not by checking the user list from firebase. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const userList = []

class SignUpForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        /*initialize my state*/
    }

    //get the user list from the database
    componentWillMount() {
        const users = database.ref('users')
        users.once('child_added', snapshot => {
          userList.push(snapshot.val())
        })
    }

    /*functions that get username from input and store into the state*/

    validateForm() {
        //in this.state, 'username' is the text input that the user entered
        const { username } = this.state

        //this is the function that checks if the username is already in use
        const findUsername = (username) => {
          userList.map(user => {
            if (user.username === username) {
              console.log("test")
              return true
            }
          })
        }

        //if username has been taken
        if (findUsername(username)) {
          console.log("found the same username in the database")
        }

        /*other validation checks*/
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/*input elements, etc*/}
                <button onClick={this.validateForm}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I do `console.log(findUsername(username))`, it returns `undefined` in my console. However, it still logs the string "test", and runs anything written inside that function. It just doesn't return `true` inside the `if` statement. I have done many checks in my code, and I can make sure that:

- the array `userList` contains every user I have stored in firebase
- this.state.username is the actual text input that the user enters
- `console.log(user.username === username)` when iterating through `userList` returns true
- `render()` function works properly

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, and I apologize if there is any ambiguity or lack of information in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function does not return anything, console log is undefined. You are returning true inside the map, but the findUsername itself does not return anything.
To check if a user exists, you can simply do this.

```
const hasUser = userList.find(user => user.username === username);
if(!hasUser) {
  //no user present. you can proceed further.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `return true` is returning from the anonymous function that you passed to `userList.map()`, not from the function findUsername.  `userList.map()` won't propagate that return value from the inner anonymous function.

If you want to know if the `userList` array contains some string, it's not clear to me at all why you're using `map()`.  It seems to me if you want a boolean that indicates if an array contains a string, you'd want to use [contains()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) instead:

```
return userList.contains(username)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was indeed the case! I used .map() since the userList array contains of objects that have properties of username, email, name, surname, etc. and I would like to only select the username property of each user, so I thought using .map() would be the solution